# Add attachment context menu Outlook 2013

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2013

I'm working on project which uses Outlook to perform a process when you hit an attachment with mouse's right clik.

The project was working fine till Outlook 2013.
I have found this post which explains why it does not work anymore :

> In Outlook 2013 they've deleted all built-in Commandbars and commandbar controls completely. For this reason you cannot access and use built-in main menus, context menus, and toolbars in Outlook 2013. The AttachmentContextMenuDisplay and ContextMenuclose events are not supported in Outlook 2013 for the same reason.

[Link to the post](https://www.add-in-express.com/forum/read.php?FID=5&TID=12507)

Indeed, my program crashed due to this event which is not triggered :

```
this.Application.AttachmentContextMenuDisplay += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_AttachmentContextMenuDisplayEventHandler(Application_AttachmentContextMenuDisplay);
```

Do you guys have any idea about how to make it works for Outlook 2013 ?
I'm still looking for information.

Many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The solution was in the post I've found...

Here's the XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <contextMenus>
    <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuAttachments">
      <button id="DT2MQPRContextMenuAttachments"
              label="Add to MQPR..."
              getVisible="DT2MQPRButton_GetVisible"
              onAction="OnMyButtonClick" />
    </contextMenu>
  </contextMenus>
</customUI>
```

And the method's code :

```
public void OnMyButtonClick(Office.IRibbonControl control)
{
    try
    {
        object context = control.Context;
        if (context == null) return false;
        if (context is Outlook.AttachmentSelection)
        {
            Outlook.AttachmentSelection selectedAttachments = context as Outlook.AttachmentSelection;
            SelectedAttachment = attachment[1];
            OutlookCommon._fName = SelectedAttachment.FileName;
            // etc...
        }
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(context); context = null;
        }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("attachmentButton_Click  " + ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

There we go, if it could help anyone ;)